# SFML Compilation with CMake. sh.exe not in my PATH

Tags: cmake

I tried to generate files to compile SFML with CMake but i have this error that i don't understand.

> sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:
>
> C:/Windows/system/sh.exe
>
> For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

I must be blind because i don't see it anywhere in the path. Though i'm not sure of myself, could you tell me if you see anything i should remove ?

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;

Comment: Ok, i manage to do what i wanted to do by renaming sh.exe. But i don't understand what in the path led to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an (odd) limitation of CMake.

If you use MSYS with MinGW, you'll have an `sh.exe` in your `bin/` directory which is added to PATH, thus you need to choose the `MSYS Makefiles` generator.